# How to plot a bar graph based on dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
```

This dataset has "dateRep" and "cases" columns (this dataset has more columns but it doesn't matter now).

I want to plot a bar plot where the dateRep is x-axis and cases are the y-axis.
sample data:
[image: sample data]

Comment: you can use matplotlib histograms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data can't do anything with images, I drew the simplest bar graph from similar data. If you need to make any corrections later, you can refer to the [official website](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) and various other information.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(df['date'], df['cases'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=None, interval=14, tz=None))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))

plt.show()
```

[image]